# Ego Network in Gephi does not work

Tags: neo4j

I'm using with ego network filter to get one concrete node with all its edges and connected nodes, but when I'm pressing filter button it does nothing as I'm guessing it doesn't work, because the ID column is a string type, whenever I try to import spreadsheet or spigot into Gephi ID column is always string and I can't change it. Could anyone help me?

Answer (score 2):

Make sure to press the "OK button" (near to "Node ID:" box) before click Filter button.

Comment: Hope this little unintuitive stuffs will be fixed one day